# A melhor maneira de organizar menu e footer em php é com com includes?

Tags: php

Arquivo `menu.php`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/imagens/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Digamos que eu tenha que adicionar o menu em cada *.php em que há a necessidade da página ter o menu, a melhor forma é fazendo um include? Por exemplo:

- Vamos supor que estamos no diretório raiz e estamos no index.php deste mesmo diretório, o meu `include` estaria neste caminho: 
  `include_once("Templates/menu.php");`

Agora, se eu criar um diretório chamado `home` e criar um `index.php` dentro dela (home/index.php), o caminho do  `include` acima ficaria: `include_once("../Templates/menu.php");`, o que daria muito trabalho.

Existe alguma forma simplificada de fazer um include de `menu`, `footer` etc mais "experto"?

Estava pensando em fazer em `OOP`.

Comment: Sim. Essa é a melhor maneira, caso não esteja usando MVC.

Comment: Com MVC, você consegue fazer com que a view renderize sempre o header e o footer, além do content que você precisar, assim, você precisará dar este include somente uma vez. Caso ao contrário, você pode setar constantes com o caminho e incluir a constante.

Comment: Do que jeito como demonstrou já é um jeito "experto". rsrr  Terá que fazer os includes de qualquer forma, com ou sem mvc ou oop. Aliás, oop e mvc nada tem a ver com isso. rsr

Comment: Já procurou por templates engine?
Da uma olhada se um deles não tem agrada: - [Twig](http://%20http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) - [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) - [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/pt_BR/)

Comment: Se fizer o include com caminho absoluto, nao tem o problema de se preocupar com que diretório está o arquivo que usa o include. `include_once( "$raiz_do_site_no_hd/Templates/menu.php" );` - Outra coisa boa é evitar maiúsculas nos nomes. Dê uma pesquisada em DOCUMENT_ROOT para mais detalhes de como obter o caminho absoluto da raiz do site automaticamente.

Answer (score 3):

Carlos, baseando meu conhecimento adquirido trabalhando com frameworks, eu sugiro que você monte uma estrutura para trabalhar melhor com o PHP.

Por exemplo, creio que você deve organizar seu projeto, separando cada coisa em pastas.

Exemplo:

```
app/
   index.php
   elementos/
   paginas/
   helpers.php
```

Dentro da pasta `elementos`, eu colocaria todos aquilo que é apenas parcial (menus, footers, sidebar, formulários de pesquisa reutilizáveis e etc).

Exemplo:

```
 app/
    elementos/menu.php
    elementos/footer.php
```

No seu arquivo `index.php`, você terá as configurações de sua página. Você pode utilizar uma pasta chamada `paginas` para adicionar outras páginas em php, porém que serão incluídos dinamicamente em `index.php`

No arquivo `helpers.php`, você vai incluir algumas funções que te auxiliaram no projeto.

Por exemplo, para facilitar o carregamento dos "elementos" poderíamos criar uma função lá.

```
 function element($element)
 {
     return include __DIR__ . '/elementos/' . $element . '.php';
 }
```

Assim, você pode fazer algo similar no seu arquivo index.php

```
  <?php include __DIR__ . '/helper.php'; ?>

  <html>
        <body>
           <div><?php element('menu') ?></div>
           <div><?php page($_GET['page']) ?></div>
           <div><?php element('menu') ?></div>
        </body>
  </html>
```